# Forwarding Client Authentication From LoginServer To GameServer Securely

Tags: java, authentication, networking, client, server

The simple architecture and summary of dilemma:

- **Entry Point:** *Client* successfully authenticates itself to a singleton *LoginServer* (via TCP the connection supplies valid username+password). *LoginServer* is the only Server with access to the salted login database.
- *LoginServer* intelligently selects a single *GameServer* from a list of *GameServer(s)* to assign this *Client*. After being assigned to a *GameServer*, *Client* will send I/O requests to said *GameServer* exclusively, which will be processed internally by nature of game design.
- **Dilemma**: *GameServer* contains no data of *Client* and is unaware of the "handshake" that took place between *LoginServer* and *Client*. *GameServer* is incapable of putting the piece of authentication from *LoginServer* to the appropriately mapped *Client* ... because what does it have to work with?
- **Potential Solution:** After successfully authenticating with *LoginServer*, *Client* is given a unique token to validate itself with *GameServer(s)*.

Side note: I'm assuming using anything IP-based is a security concern due to potential IP spoofing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sessions between servers and clients.

Session details should be decided by you and should be created when user login using LoginServer. Then login server should forward those details to Game server so that both CLIENT and SERVER know their identity.

Extra Reading -

[Creating a secure login using sessions and cookies in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435068/creating-a-secure-login-using-sessions-and-cookies-in-php)

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions

[What are sessions? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work)

[PHP Session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security)